# Packages missing from new install of Canopy Express

Tags: enthought, statsmodels

I just installed Canopy Express 1.4.1 (32-bit) for Windows. Among the packages that are supposed to be there (see https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/package-index/ ) are pandas and statsmodels. But after installing, neither is listed in Package Manager, either as being installed or available.

The lack of pandas is not a problem, as pip easily installs it. (Enthought notes that packages installed that way will not be listed in Package Manager, but are fully available in the Canopy User Environment. Indeed, it imports.

statsmodels is not so easy. pip only gets source, and there is no Windows installer provided by the statsmodels folks. There is a nightly Windows binary, but not (if I'm reading correctly) for the stable build. The suggested solution by statsmodels is to compile it, using MinGW, which I do not currently have installed.

With enough trouble, I imagine I could compile and install, but is there a way to save all that trouble and get the packages within Canopy, as Enthought says it should be?

Comment: windows installers for statsmodels releases are on pypi. (however not python 3.3 and 3.4 since 0.5 didn't get updated in a year.) https://pypi.python.org/pypi/statsmodels/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your Package Manager is misbehaving or you are looking in the wrong place (look in Free Packages not Community Packages).

Pandas is indeed in the Express installer, so always installed. At Canopy's python prompt, type:
   import pandas

Though sounds like you've already overwritten it with pip, not really a problem but not the cleanest path (mixing 2 different installation methods for the same package).

Statsmodels *is* listed in package manager (Free package). It is available to free users but is not yet in the Express installer.

If you still don't see these in the pkg mgr, please quit Canopy, ensure that all Canopy processes have terminated (easiest way... log out of Windows, then back in), and restart Canopy.

Comment: Logging off (restarting the computer) made no difference on the original install. On that, I had followed the instructions allowing me to install for all users. I uninstalled and re-installed Canopy, using the default setup, and the packages were there.